# add_image_size is scaling, even though crop is set to true

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, images, cropping

I am trying to crop a 1000 x 648 image to 400 x 400.
I use this code in functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size('shop-size', 400, 400, array(center,center) );
add_image_size('shop-size2', 401, 400, true );
```

then i go to the regenerate plugin and run it.  While I run it I open up wp-content uploads to check out what's going on.

I watch as it creates a 400x259 image that is scaled.  The regenerate plugin even says it is going to do a 400x400 cropped to fit for shop-size, and then proceeds not to.

I checked if gd is loaded with this and it returns 'gd loaded'

```
<?php if (extension_loaded('gd')) 
     { 
         echo "gd loaded"; 
     } else { 
         echo "not loaded"; 
} ?>
```

I also tried hooking it into after_theme_setup like this:

```
function add_custom_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'map-size', 199, 199, array('center','center') );
    add_image_size('shop-size', 599, 599, array('center','center') );
    add_image_size('discover-size', 749, 620, array('center','center'));
    add_image_size( 'map-size1', 198, 199, true );
    add_image_size('shop-size1', 598, 599, true );
    add_image_size('discover-size1', 748, 620, true);
}

add_action('after_setup_theme','add_custom_sizes');
```

however as i regenerate it still makes a 198x165 instead of 198x199 (from 768 x 641)

The parent is called 'rise' by thrive themes.  I contacted them but they said they don't have support for dev questions.

The parent only uses add_image_size once, i tried removing this but I still had the scaling instead of cropping issue.

I've included the rise files below.  I have a hunch they do some kind of custom scaling thing?  And i will have to over-ride this some how?

thrive image optimization file - https://pastebin.com/1QEa6YJv
thrive functions - https://pastebin.com/pAqBt285

Can anyone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: `array(center,center)` is an array of two _constants_ called `center`. These need to be strings: `array('center','center')`. Not sure if that's exactly the problem, but it stuck out.

Comment: @JacobPeattie hey thanks for responding! i tried your suggestion but same thing happens, it scales instead of cropping

Comment: And how about second image size? Does it create it correctly?

Comment: 'https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35833/the-post-thumbnail-hard-cropping-not-working-no-matter-what' says you need to hook the function for adding images sizes on 'after_theme_support'. would mind to give a try ??

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż using true scales too, doesn't crop

Comment: @VayuDev ok i tried your suggestion, but got same scaling result.  Added code I used to the main post

Comment: I have three suggestions:   
(1) In Thrive options, there is `thrive_get_theme_options( 'image_optimization_type' )`. Can you reproduce the issue with this option turned Off?   
(2) Also, can you test this with another theme activated? (Just to make sure server settings are ok).   
(3) Is `WP_DEBUG` set to `true` in `wp-config.php`? It should be, just in case we are missing something here.

Answer (score 1):

from your question i under that you want fixed size cropped images when you upload image, why don't you use `wp_get_image_editor`. I used it in my project where i wanted cropped images of fixed size so i did this code.

```
$path = $newPath['basedir'].'/newImgas/';
$cropfile = uniqid() . '.png';
$cropfilename = $path.$cropfile;
$cropImage = home_url(). '/wp-content/uploads/newImgas/'.$cropfile;
$c_image = wp_get_image_editor($newImage);
if ( ! is_wp_error($c_image) ) {
  $c_image->resize( 600, 600, TRUE);
  $c_image->save( $cropfilename );
}
```

You can find example [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_image_editor). Please reply me if it isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem could be, that you need to set the high priority (try 101, or even 999 if it solves):

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_custom_sizes',  101 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that GD is loaded doesn't mean it is actually used for handling the images. From the pastebin code you give I conclude that your theme comes bundled with the [Kraken image optimizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kraken-image-optimizer/) (as a separate plugin or bundled with the theme in some other way).

Since using [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) only places the data in an array, it is up to the image handling function to actually use it. Normally this is done by the function [`wp_save_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_save_image/), which allows for any image editor to be used (in the line where it says: `$img = wp_get_image_editor`).

So, probably the Kraken editor is ignoring the crop setting. You'll have to find the plugin settings and modify them, if your theme lets you. Kraken is a paid scheme, so there may be limitations.

Alternatively, you could use the [`wp_image_editors`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_image_editors-9/) filter to change the image editor back to GD, but as I don't know how the theme uses Kraken I'm not sure what the effect of doing this would be.